# Facebook API, PHP SDK getRequestForNextPage()

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm developing a web app (with PHP SDK) that basically takes user posts of last year and does some kind of analysis on it.
Until now i used to load the data with a recursive function that everytime gets the content from the paging link and calls itself again with that data.
i've just discovered that i can use getRequestForNextPage(); so i'm trying to use this function but i got some troubles , seems that getRequestForNextPage() do not respect request's parameters. I know my explanation is pretty confused, here a simplified version of my code:

```
$thedate= strtotime('now ,-1 year');
$today = strtotime('now');
$richiesta ="/me/posts?since=".$thedate."&until=".$today;
$request = new FacebookRequest(  // richiedo i miei statuses
$session,
 'GET',
 $richiesta
 );
$respons = $request->execute();
function looper($response){     
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();             
    $nextPageRequest = $response->getRequestForNextPage();
    $respy = $nextPageRequest->execute();       
    $x = $graphObject->getProperty('data');
    $y = $x->asArray(); 
    $counter = 0 ;      
    foreach ($y as $el){
        //do something                      
    }   
                    
    if ( $respy != false ){ 
        looper($respy);
    } else {                
        return;
    }
}

looper($respons);`
```

it seems that that function just keep to iterate even if the posts are older than 1 year.
do getRequestForNextPage() just dont care about request parameters? it just check if there is a "next" paging link in the graph object? Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: The "next" paging link should respect your request parameters.  What is the SDK returning as a link?  Have you tried looking at your requests in the Graph API Explorer to see what it is actually returning for paging links?  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: yes , and as i said, before of i used another approach (with the same request) and everything was fine, but now seems that using getRequestForNextPage() should be more efficient.
You are right if i var_dump $nextPageRequest i can see parameters, but i've tried in graph explorer and i think  i've figured out wich is the problem:
Even if i have not next data to show i have a next paging link that returns and empty object. Is this a bug? any suggestion on how to bypass this?

Comment: That's working correctly. There will be "next" and "previous" links, even if the response is empty.